# how to create command with argument in laravel 5(use phpmd as php artisan phpmd )?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have develop a app in which I want to use linter locally from project.

Like `php artisan phpmd <file> <ruleset>`

I have seen vedios but I got of laravel 4 but I want laravel 5 with proper steps.Can you please tell me or refer any link?

Comment: problem is I can not find `fire` mthod in phpmd.php file

Comment: You should use `handle()` method for your code. I wonder why did you unticked my answer? Is it something wrong with it?

Comment: Ok dude I did..but if you can then pls ans my edited question if you can,i would be more happy.this ans I expected from you and i thought you give me later so i unticked :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to just use short command? Laravel will not help you here, you can use alias (depends on OS you use) or script (like .bat in Windows) which will run command with arguments for you. Also, don't forget to include your script to the global PATH variable (also depends on OS).  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)

Comment: I mean to what I run in `phpmd` same thing run with `php artisan`. requirement is that after cloning this project from github no other thing would be install. and run `phpmd` from php artisan. this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#command-structure) and use `$signature` variable:

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user} {from}';
```

Here, `user` and `from` are arguments.

Then you can use these arguments:

```
echo $this->argument('user');
```

Comment: ok done with it.can you tell me how to integrate `phpmd` as artisan command?

Comment: Create a command and then register it https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#registering-commands - after that your command will work.