# Use phpmd as php artisan phpmd

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

Hello, I am working on app in which i need to use phpmd as php artisan phpmd(i ). means make phpmd as local command and use in project.requirement is when i clone the project no additional things should be required and one can freely run `php artisan phpmd` command.which work same as `phpmd`

command will be like `php artisan phpmd <file> <ruleset>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're already have your Artisan command ready and working. Then best approach will be creating `.bat` script for Windows and `.sh` script for Unix systems and placing it in Laravel project's root directory.

For example, `phpmd.bat` file can look like that:

```
php artisan phpmd %1 %2
```

When you'll clone the project, you can just run `phpmd someFile someRuleset` from Laravel project directory and it should work exactly as `php artisan phpmd someFile someRuleset` command.

For Ubuntu, Mac and other Unix OS `.sh` file will look similar:

```
#!/bin/sh
php artisan phpmd $1 $2
```

Comment: ans is good nut i want to use 'phpmd artisan phpmd <><>` instead of `phpmd`..which is already running

Comment: From your question and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476418/how-to-create-command-with-argument-in-laravel-5use-phpmd-as-php-artisan-phpmd/36477066#36477066 - I've undertood that `phpmd` is your own custom artisan command. Is this correct? Or you're talking about using https://phpmd.org/ in your project?

Comment: or directly I can use `php artisan phpmd` than it will be better.

Comment: Just change php to phpmd then: phpmd artisan phpmd

Comment: will it work localy while clonning? i dought....well i am beginner so there is understanding problem :)

Comment: If phpmd mocks php, then it should work if you put `phpmd.phar` in Laravel folder and run it like `php phpmd.phar artisan $1 $2`.

Comment: hey you gave me hope,I am near solution...one error came like
`Can't find the custom report class`

Comment: hey your solution is correct..path error come i dun no where to give argument path(it changes because i moved in laravel)